# Error al recibir notificación Push

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification

Es una aplicación que recibe notificación cuando otra aplicación escribe en la base de datos de Firebase. El error:

```
Unable to instantiate service firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService:  
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService" on path: DexPathList[[zip file…..
```

El manifest:

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

    <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>

    <service
        android:name="firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
    <service
        android:name="firebase.MyFirebaseIdService">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT"/>
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
</application>
```

El index.js

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.respuesta = functions.database.ref('/pedido/{pedidoId}').onCreate((snap, context) => {
  const createdData = snap.val(); // data that was created

  var topic="rotiseria";

  console.log(“”+context.params.id);
  console.log(""+idPedido);

  var payload = {
                    data: {
                            idPedido: 'pedido1',
                            remitente: 'Raquel Mansilla'
                            },
                            topic: topic
                        };

          admin.messaging().send(payload)
            .then((response) => {
              // Response is a message ID string.
              console.log('Successfully sent message:', response);
            })
            .catch((error) => {
              console.log('Error sending message:', error);
            });

            return null;


          });
```

Y la clase MyFirebaseMessagingService:

```
public class MyFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

@Override
public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {

    // Check if message contains a data payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
        Log.d("Message data payload: ", ""+remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    // Check if message contains a notification payload.
    if (remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
        Log.d("Message Notification Body: ","" + remoteMessage.getData());
    }

    showNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("idPedido"),remoteMessage.getData().get("remitente"));

}


@Override
public void onMessageSent(String s) {
    super.onMessageSent(s);
}


private void showNotification(String idPedido,String remitente) {

    String titulo = (idPedido == null || idPedido.isEmpty()) ? "Notificación importante" : idPedido;

    Intent notIntent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PedidosFragment.class);
    notIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP);

    Log.d("Notificacion",idPedido);

    PendingIntent contIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, notIntent, 0);

    NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setContentIntent(contIntent)
            .setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.ic_launcher)
            .setContentTitle(titulo)
            .setContentText(remitente)
            .setAutoCancel(true);


    notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(contIntent);

    Uri alarmSound = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
    notificationBuilder.setSound(alarmSound);


    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());

}

}
```

Bueno, saludos!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día el error se encuentra en esta linea :

`android:name="firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">`

solo agrega un "." antes de firebase :

`android:name=".firebase.MyFirebaseMessagingService">`

y te recomiendo que actualizes las librerias de firebase ya que la manera en que implementas "InstanceIDService" es obsoleta saludos.

Comment: muchas gracias @serna!!!